# How to get edittext and text value from listview using baseadapter in android

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I am using base adapter and but could not getting value when click button, only passed value getting but edited value not gettng. why this, could you find out the where is the wrong in my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView listview;

    Button getall;
     HashMap<String,String> row;
    HashMap<Integer, String> mValues;
    private EditorAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listview=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.ageListView);
        getall=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_ger);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

       for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            row = new HashMap<String, String>();
            row.put("name","name  "+i);
            row.put("value",""+i);
            data.add(row);
       }
        adapter= new EditorAdapter(getBaseContext(), data);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        //notifyDataSetChanged();
        getall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String allValues="";
                ArrayList<String> valueList = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i=0;i<adapter.getCount();i++){
                    allValues +=((HashMap<String,String>)adapter.getItem(i)).get("value")+ ",";
                    valueList.add(((HashMap<String,String>)adapter.getItem(i)).get("value"));
                }
                // use this valueList as per ur requirement
                allValues = allValues.substring(0,allValues.length()-1);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,allValues,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });



    }
    class EditorAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        Context context;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> data;

        public EditorAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> data){

            this.context = context;
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return data.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int pos) {
            return data.get(pos);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int pos) {
            return pos;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if(convertView==null){
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_view,null,false);
                holder.editPropertyValue = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edit_age);
                holder.propertyName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.propertyName.setText(data.get(position).get("name"));
            holder.editPropertyValue.setText(data.get(position).get("value"));

            convertView.setTag(holder);
            return convertView;
        }

        class ViewHolder {
            EditText editPropertyValue;
            TextView propertyName;
        }

}
```

Here, if click button after edit the value only display previous value 0,1,2. why not if i enter other value.

Comment: Because you don't save the new value after editing. You need do update the item in your ArrayList **data** (inside your adapter)

Comment: Where are you entering 'new values'? I can't see this 'after editing' code here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if(convertView==null){
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_view,null,false);
                holder.editPropertyValue = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edit_age);
                holder.propertyName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.propertyName.setText(data.get(position).get("name"));
            holder.editPropertyValue.setText(data.get(position).get("value"));

            holder.editPropertyValue.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){// add text watcher to update your data after editing
                 public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                     HashMap<String,String> row = data.get(position); // get the item from your ArrayList
                     row.put("value", holder.editPropertyValue.getText());// update your HashMap
                     data.set(position, row); // update your data ( your ArrayList )
                 }
                 public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
                 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
            }); 
            convertView.setTag(holder);
            return convertView;
        }
```

Comment: I got this, **The method entrySet() in the type HashMap<String,String> is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)** , i cannot update data on hashmap.

Comment: Am sorry, try: row.put(key, holder.editPropertyValue.getText()); #I've updated my code.

Comment: still not working after button click, old value displayed, new updated value could not displayed.

Comment: I updated again my code, I misunderstand your HashMap structure. I  thought that "name" is the key and "value" is the entry.